# Spring boot cloud oaut2 custom field

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to build an app that use custom oaut2 authentication with spring boot. I want to set a groupId for principal and use it for spring jpa on resource server.

```
@Query("select o from BusinessObject o where o.owner.id = ?#{principal.claims['companyId']} or 1=?#{hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') ? 1 : 0}")
List<BusinessObject> findBusinessObjectsForCurrentUserById();
```

How to succeed this?